# Reward Video ad not display admobpro cordova

Tags: cordova, admob, cordova-admob

I have been trying to implement Reward Video in my app, but for some weird reason my Reward ads are not displaying.

But When I use, the test ad ID the test video ad from google shows up.

I am using [Cordova Admob-pro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/tree/master/docs) plugin.

In the docs of the plugin it reads,

> adId, string, Ad unit Id for the reward video Ad. You need configure mediation in AdMob portal.

What do I need to configure in the Admob Portal? Can someone help?

PS: All the other ads that is banner, interstitial ads are also working dine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (using plugin v2.32.6) where interstitial adverts are working on android and ios, but rewarded ads aren't showing on ios.

In trying various options I discovered it was because I was relying on the autoshow flag and that simply calling showRewardVideoAd() in my onAdLoaded event handler works fine.

I hope this might be of help.